# Use ambient declarations as if it were part of a namespace

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-package

The npm package that I'm writing has a dependency on a npm package whose index.d.ts contains a lot of ambient declarations.
Example:

```
// other package's index.d.ts file
declare function emit(eventName: string, ...args: any[]): void
declare function TriggerEvent(eventName: string, ...args: any[]): void
// .. etc (no exports)
```

I would like to make it so that the project consuming my npm package would need to use "Engine.emit" or "Engine.TriggerEvent" instead of directly using "emit"/"TriggerEvent". Is there any way I can do that? I think an option would be creating a wrapper module, but I wouldn't want to manually add each ambient declaration of my dependency package.